# Creating a software using visual basics and mysql?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008, installation

I am creating a software for keeping records. I am using Visual Basics from Visual Studios 2008 as front end and mysql as back end to store my data. My question is ... how can I make this software a single setup file, easy to install and use. Means that user need not to have Visual Studios and mysql installed in his system. He just have to install my software and that is it. 
How it can be done please help.

Comment: MySQL is a server type database, which means you'll need a service to host the database. You just can't embed something like this. You can make an installer project and add the prerequisite software before installing. If you really want an install all method, use a database like Access. It works even if you don't have Office installed.

Answer (score 0):

You cant embed MySQL into a Visual Studio App. From the MySQL [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/libmysqld.html):

> The embedded server library is based on the client/server version of
>   MySQL, which is written in C/C++. Consequently, the embedded server
>   also is written in C/C++. There is no embedded server available in
>   other languages

You could try it with Microsoft's version of an embedded DB, SQL Server Compact Edition: [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx)

If that doesn't seem like a good fit, you could try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)